# Internet connectivity issues

Tags: wireless, internet

I have installed Ubuntu 23.10 version on my laptop and I am frequently facing internet connectivity issues.Ubuntu is unable to connect to wireless connection. Is there a way to solve this issue permanently because last time one I searched this issue and  got around a command which first helped me but now even that's not working.

Comment: Is Ubuntu the only operating system on the laptop or do you have Windows installed as well?

Comment: Yes, I only have Ubuntu installed